# how to divide a number in to parts so that it falls in the range.....!

Tags: java

I have a number 15000.

1. For `0-5000` i don't have to apply any discount
2. For `5001-10000` i have to apply `10%` discount so (`5000+4500=9500`)
3. And for above `10000` i have to apply discount of `20%` (`5000+4500+4000=13500`)

How can we divide a number so that it falls in the particular range?

Comment: I don't know how applying 10% discount on 5000 makes it 9500.

Comment: @DarshanMehta It's like U.S. tax brackets, you pay the first `5000` in full, and then get a 10% discount on the second `5000`, so you only pay `4500` for that part.  The total owed is then `9500`.

Comment: corrected it to 13500

Comment: How to know why you put the java tag on this question; or what your question is at all ...

Comment: @GhostCat, presumably, the OP is requesting a solution written in Java.

Comment: Sure. And if i wouldnt be such an egoist b****d, I would share my code with him that I wrote during the last 3 minutes that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done like this:

```
int amount = ...
int total = 0;
if (amount > 10_000) {
    // Apply 20 % on the amount above 10 K
    total += (amount - 10_000) * 0.8d;
    amount = 10_000;
}
if (amount > 5_000) {
    // Apply 10 % on the amount above 5 K
    total += (amount - 5_000) * 0.9d;
    amount = 5_000;
}
// Apply 0 % on the rest
total += amount;
```